# Mirorred text in ComboBox inside TimerTask

Tags: java, javafx

I have editable `ComboBox` which should work like autosuggest. When user reaches 3 characters of the input and it's been 1500 miliseconds since last character was written it sends a request which returns `JSON`. I parse it and put in the dropdown of the `ComboBox`. Till now it works well. But after the dropdown is filled and user continues typing (let's say he wants be more specific in his query) the cursor is locked at the position and produces mirror reflected image of anything typed.
*For example*, I want get info about the 4th Harry Potter movie:

1. I type "Harry Potter and the ",
2. wait 1500ms until request calls, receive response and dropdown is filled,
3. then I want to be more specific and choose Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire. So I continue typing "Goblet of Fire" but as you can see all the characters are mirrored.

Does anyone have clue what's wrong about my code? I bet there's some issue with TimerTask, but I don't know exactly.

```
    
List<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
combo.getEditor().setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            public void handle(KeyEvent ke) {
            TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
                    public void run() {
                        if (System.currentTimeMillis() - last > 1500) {
                            last = System.currentTimeMillis();
                            if (combo.getEditor().getText().length() > 3 && !stopFlag) {
                                String query = combo.getEditor().getText();
                                String search = query.replace(" ", "%20");
                                HttpRequest request = //..request call (not important)
                                HttpResponse<String> responses;
                                try {
                                    responses = HttpClient.newHttpClient().send(request,
                                            HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
                                    String jsonString = responses.body();
                                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
                                    JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("d");
    
                                    String actualValue = combo.getEditor().getText();
                                    
                                    
                                    for (Object itemObj : arr) {
                                        JSONObject itemJSON = (JSONObject) itemObj;
                                        String nazev = itemJSON.getString("l");
                                        try {
                                            int ro = itemJSON.getInt("y");
                                            String res = nazev + " (" + ro + ")";
                                            listItems.add(res);
                                        } catch (JSONException je) {
                                            continue;
                                        }
                                    }
                                        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                        combo.getItems().clear();
                                        for (String item : listItem){
                                            combo.getItems().add(item);
                                        }
                                            combo.getEditor().setText(actualValue);
                                        }
                                        ((TextInputControl)combo.getEditor()).end();
                                            combo.show();
                                        }
                                    });
                                    
                                } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e1) {
                                    e1.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            } 
                        } 
                    }
                };
                Timer timer = new Timer("Timer");
                long delay = 1800L;
```

[image]

EDIT:
I moved all the UI code into `Platform.runLater()` so it should happened at the final phase. By the way, to be specific - the timer here works like a waiting mechanism that expects a key to be pressed (or not to be). So it keeps updating the `last` variable value and if the gap between last two key presses is greater than 1500miliseconds it calls request. If you think of better solution, I would be grateful if you let me know.

Comment: Perhaps using a [ScheduledService](https://javadoc.io/static/org.openjfx/javafx-graphics/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/concurrent/ScheduledService.html) may be an alternative to Timer and TimerTask.  For regularly scheduled non-IO work, I'd suggest a PauseTransition, but, in this case, with IO involved, ScheduledService would seem most applicable.

Comment: Your fragment appears to be updating the scene graph from a background thread; see [*Concurrency in JavaFX*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm).

Comment: You are currently doing a weird combination of accessing some scene graph properties off of the JavaFX thread and then doing other work on scene graph properties on the JavaFX thread.  You should never access the active scene graph off of the JavaFX thread. (oops, cross-posted with Trashgod, essentially the same thing).

Comment: I'd also suggest adding a bit more structure to this.  Separate the service from the UI.  Put the service behind an interface.  For example, SuggestionProvider, which provides suggestions for a given input and only works with raw data, no UI elements at all.  Then program your UI to that interface.  Provide a test implementation that implements the Service using some pre-defined data and ensure that works fine with your UI implementation.  Then switch over to the real implementation which uses the HTTP calls and JSON and test that.  You don't have to do it that way, it's just a suggestion.

Comment: @jewelsea I edited the post. Was it worth it?

Comment: "Was it worth it?" are you asking me if it was worth editing your post? If so, I don't know, that is for you to decide.

Comment: Edit says: "I moved all the UI code into Platform.runLater()".  But you haven't, you are still accessing scene graph properties from the timer thread, which is not the JavaFX thread, e.g. using calls such as `combo.getEditor().getText()`, which leaves your code and the JavaFX framework code in general vulnerable to [race conditions](https://www.baeldung.com/cs/race-conditions).  Whether that is the cause of your immediate reversal problem, I don't know.  I can't just run your code and reproduce your issue because I don't have your http server or app code, there is no [mcve].

Comment: You're still accessing GUI properties outside JavaFX thread, even though you say opposite.